# how to share USB Passthrough with no mass storage on hyper-v

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I have setup a Windows 10 hyper-v running on Windows server 2019
Client Hyper-V to be able to continue using a discontinued application for a short period of time. I understand that this requires USB Passthrough, but can't seem to find anything more for documentation beyond enabling USB mass storage.  I'll take any suggestions on this, if anyone has any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

AS long as your guest has access to network, you can use some usb over network solution, such as :

- https://www.net-usb.com/
- https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/
- http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network-download.html#tab_usbnet-win-current